# derivative of $f(x)=(4x^2+9)^7(7x^2+3)^{12}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f(x)=(4x^2+9)^7(7x^2+3)^{12}$

I used the product rule and came up with:
$y'=4(x^2+9)^7(168(7x^2+3)^{11})+56x(4x^2+9)^6(7x^2+3)^{12}$

Why is this wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In the first term you have a $4$ factor that should be inside the parenthesis:
$$ 4(x^2+9)^7 \longrightarrow (4x^2+9)^7$$
Also, you forgot the $x$ when making the derivative of $(7x^2+3)^{12}$:
$$168(7x^2+3)^{11} \longrightarrow 168x(7x^2+3)^{11}$$

Answer (score 2):

Logarithmic differentiation makes this very much simpler:

$$\log f(x) = 7 \log (4x^2 + 9) + 12 \log (7x^2  + 3).$$  Therefore, $$(\log f(x))' = \frac{7(8x)}{4x^2 + 9} + \frac{12(14x)}{7x^2 + 3}.$$  But since $$(\log f(x))' = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$ by the chain rule, it follows that $$f'(x) = f(x) (\log f(x))',$$ which is easy to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing $x$ on the first term (it should be $(4x^2+9)^7(168x(7x^2+3)^{11})$ and there is a typo with $4$ (it should be inside the parenthesis)

Answer (score 1):

Using product rule, it is $$\frac{d(4x^2+9)^7}{dx} \cdot (7x^2+3)^{12} + \frac {d (7x^2+3)^{12} }{dx} \cdot (4x^2+9)^7$$
= $$7 (4x^2+9)^6 \cdot 8x \cdot (7x^2+3)^{12} + 12 (7x^2+3)^{11} \cdot 14x \cdot (4x^2+9)^7$$